# Getting future date using NSDate and NSTimeInterval

Tags: ios, nstimeinterval

I'm creating a simple timer but am failing to get the resulting date that I'm after.

My problem is that I'm getting -34481.274523 from my NSTimeInterval (nslog at the end) whereas I'm wanting the number of seconds since the current date (`currentDate`). `stopDate` is always a date before `currentDate`.

The code snippet below is called from an nstimer every second. Rather than simply increment an int I'm using a date as it's easier to perform other date related calculations on and format for display.

Here is my code:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:stopDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss"];

NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];

NSLog(@"nstimeinterval: %f", timeInterval);

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components: ( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:timerDate];
NSLog(@"year: %li", (long)components.year);
if (components.year == 2000) {
    timeString = @"00:00";

    return;
}

NSLog(@"timer: %@", timeString);

timerTicksForCounter = timeString;

NSLog(@"hour: %li", (long)components.hour);

//Used to update uilabel
[self updateTimerLabel];


if (components.year < 2000) {
    return;
}

if (components.hour == 0) {

..... I'm doing a bunch of stuff here
```

Comment: BTW - it makes no sense to create another `NSDate` from `timeInterval`. `timeInterval` already gives you the number of seconds. Simple math will give you minutes and seconds from that interval.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. Forgetting the code you posted for a moment. What is your goal with your `stopDate`?

Comment: @rmaddy - If StopDate is before currentDate, shouldn't it be positive?  I just ran a quick test.

Comment: @Logan Yeah, you are right. I was confused in my earlier comment.

Comment: ok I've added more of my code..should make more sense now. How can I get the correct year, rather than 1970?

Comment: ..yes it should be positive.

Comment: @rmaddy - Whew, I'm glad, I was sitting here having an identity crisis with my code! :)

Comment: Have you logged your dates to ensure that stopDate is in fact earlier.  Everything leads me to believe it's not.

Comment: You're right...it looks like that is what's happening

Comment: OK fixed this problem, now I'm getting +10 hours on timerDate when it should only be a few seconds